# Pasar de String a Código de barras en JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo un programa en java que lo que hace es crear un documento word, en el cual, tiene que haber un código de barras. Hasta ahora yo pasaba la cadena de datos y al crear el word, mostraba un código de barras, que no era legible por las maquinas.

Yo le pasaba esto:

> 123456

Pero he descubierto, que el texto que le debería de pasar para que fuese legible por el lector es este:

> Í,BXLÎ

Este es el texto ya formateado a **code128**.

¿Alguien sabe como pasar de un string normal a ese formato en java?

Adjunto el codigo actual, que "crea" el codigo de barras, con string, en vez de con el formato code128.

```
    package ieci.tdw.ispac.rules.plantillas.cda;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import ieci.tdw.ispac.api.errors.ISPACException;
import ieci.tdw.ispac.api.errors.ISPACRuleException;
import ieci.tdw.ispac.api.item.IItem;
import ieci.tdw.ispac.api.item.IItemCollection;
import ieci.tdw.ispac.api.rule.IRule;
import ieci.tdw.ispac.api.rule.IRuleContext;
import ieci.tdw.ispac.constantes.Constantes;
import ieci.tdw.ispac.ispaclib.utils.StringUtils;
import ieci.tdw.ispac.rules.PLRecursos;


/*
    Clase para codificar los numero del codigo de barras y convertirlos a Code 128 
    para que puedan ser leidos por el aparato lector de Codigo de barras.
*/

public class PLCDACreateBarCode implements IRule {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PLRecursos.class);

public boolean init(IRuleContext rulectx) throws ISPACRuleException {
    return true;
}

public boolean validate(IRuleContext rulectx) throws ISPACRuleException {
    return true;
}

public Object execute(IRuleContext rulectx) throws ISPACRuleException{


    IItemCollection coleccionItem = null;
    String cod_barras = "";
    boolean esFalso=true;
    try {
        String numExp = rulectx.getNumExp();

        coleccionItem = rulectx.getClientContext().getAPI().getEntitiesAPI().getEntities(Constantes.TABLA_LIQUIDACION, numExp);

        Iterator it = coleccionItem.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            IItem item = (IItem) it.next();
            cod_barras = StringUtils.nullToEmpty(item.getString(Constantes.CAMPO_LIQ_COD_BARRAS));

            if(cod_barras != null && !"".equals(cod_barras)){
                parseTo128(cod_barras);
            }

        } 

    } catch (ISPACException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }


    return cod_barras;
}

public String parseTo128(String cod_barras){



    return cod_barras;
}

@Override
public void cancel(IRuleContext arg0) throws ISPACRuleException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: Hola Urrutias. Qué has investigado? Has probado algo? Muestranos tus intentos para poder ayudarte a arreglarlo. y vuelve a leer [ask] para hacer preguntas de mayor calidad. Un saludo

Comment: He encontrado una forma, pero creo que no es la mejor.. Hay una libreria llamada iTextSharp que lo que hace, en vez de escribir el string en el work, pone la imagen directamente.. Pero no me sirve.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto a ver si te puede ayudar http://www.javaroots.com/2015/12/how-to-generate-barcode-128-in-java.html

Comment: Muchas gracias @Edu3D , creo que me puede servir, si cojo el String ya formateado a code128 antes que que cree la imagen.